# PHP filter to get HTTP / HTTPS using preg_match regex

Tags: php, regex

This is a HTTP Request sent from a C/C++ Application, Now i want to filter to get HTTP/HTTPS to print the HTTP / HTTPS information. How do i go about this???

```
<?php

$logz = '/server/order.php?&IP=127.0.0.1?&hWid={e29ac6c0-7037-11de-816d-******************}&pcName=USER-PC&processName=C:Program FilesInternet Exploreriexplore.exe&buffer=POST /server/order.php HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: app1ication/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: localhost
Content-Length: 272
Cache-Control: no-cache

/server/order.php?&IP=127.0.0.1?&hWid={e29ac6c0-7037-11de-816d-******************}&pcName=USER-PC&processName=C:Program FilesInternet Exploreriexplore.exe&buffer=https://localhost/test/logon.php username=kazim&password=kazim&login_button.x=0&login_button.y=0XÀž»}ÞÓŸýÁÊð#(˜Ð';

preg_match('/^(http|https):\\/\\/[a-z0-9_]+([\\-\\.]{1}[a-z_0-9]+)*\\.[_a-z]{2,5}'.'((:[0-9]{1,5})?\\/.*)?$/i', $logz,$match);
echo $match[1];

?>
```

**Edit**

i want it to post just this **https://localhost/test/logon.php** thats what

Comment: You want the value of the `buffer` parameter in the `/server/order.php` line?

Comment: FYI order.php will receive the arguments already cut for you, in the $_GET array.  `$_GET["buffer"]` will give you what you need.

Comment: just the http/https is fine here, i want to use regex in this case. @Nic3500

Comment: Help us help you.  Please edit your question with the exact output you want from the sample data you have in there.  "the http/https" is unclear to me.

Comment: @Nic3500 what i want is to print only the Https string (which is the url) thank you

Comment: Post what you want in the question.  The exact text.

Comment: @Nic3500 edited, you can see what i want at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this:

```
$result = preg_match('/(http|https):\/\/[a-z0-9]+[a-z0-9_\/]*/',$logz,$match);
```

$result is just to get the return code from preg_match.

In your sample data, you have a space after the page: `.../logon.php username=...`.  With this it is quite easy, just do not include the space in `[a-z0-9_\/]*`.  And adding `\/` in there will let it match all `/` in the pattern, wherever they might be.

In your pattern, you doubled each .  But that is not required, since `\/` means to not treat the `/` after the `\` like the regex delimiter that preg_match expects.  One `\` is enough.